# Typescript/Angular 2 - Multi-level [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having this code below:

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col class="alignCenter" col-6 col-sm-6 no-padding>
     <p>Pulse (bpm)</p>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-6 col-sm-6 no-padding>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="form.content.vitals.pulse"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

When I make the request to back-end, sometimes the "vitals" level is undefined, and I get an exception.

The solution with *ngIf="form.content.vitals", and not adding the input to the DOM is not a good one for this case, because if I don't have anything in the "vitals", then the input will not appear at all.

I also don't want to manually put "vitals" value to {}, because I have many more other levels like this one.

I know I could use this:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-input type="text" [ngModel]="form.content.vitals?.pulse" (ngModelChange)="form.content.vitals.pulse = $event"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

It was way easier in Angular 1, but I'm thinking, are there other possibilities of solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> When I make the request to back-end, sometimes the "vitals" level is undefined, and I get an exception.

Then when you receive the data from the backend, check if it is `undefined` and load a default object with valid values for all properties, like `''`.

If you plan on saving/posting these data you will have to check them individually anyway.

To that end I suggest you look at Angular's [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder), that will allow you you attach predefined or custom validators to each form element.